# How to automatically apply permissions to new files added (via Windows PC) to a shared folder on Mac Mini (not server)

Tags: permission

I have a shared folder setup on Mac Mini (not server) running on Catalina. I am able to access the folder via Windows PC connected on same network but when I create a file (say a css file) using Windows PC in that shared folder on Mac, other users are NOT able to access those new files.

I did setup ACL inheritance permissons as described here http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4149

I also setup inheritance permissions on the parent holder with the following command.

```
sudo chmod -R +a "group:REPLACE_WITH_YOURGROUP_NAME:allow readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,file_inherit,directory_inherit" REPLACE_WITH_PATH_TO_PARENT_SHARED_FOLDER
```

BUT IT IS NOT WORKING.

Is it because I am using Mac Mini (not server)?

What am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: What do you get when you check the permission from Windows PC's Explorer. Does that folder has full rights as required ?